# Setting up ReactJS with MobX decorators without TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I have read [this tutorial](https://swizec.com/blog/mobx-with-create-react-app/swizec/7158), and it seems like it doesn't work for me, probably because its outdated.

I get the following error when using the `@inject` decoration:

```
./src/index.js
Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.
```

I can't really find a way to properly set up decorations for mobX without using TypeScript?

Comment: This is the MobX documentation page for what you want to do: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html#enabling-decorator-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use babel and it's plugins to transpile your code.

To use decorators use [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators)

In your babelrc file add plugins property:

```
{
  // your other babel settings
  "plugins": ["plugin-proposal-decorators"]
}
```

Comment: When I install that npm, babelrc file is not being created?

Comment: No. Look for how to set up .babelrc file and what packages you might need.Probably you're going to need babel-core, babel-loader, babel-preset-env, babel-preset-react. Also, look how to set up webpack. There are plenty of tutorials, I'm sure you can figure it out.